# Filter belongs_to items in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Bookshelf` model that `has_many :books`, and i need to filter books by bookshelf.category_id

```
books: id, bookshelf_id
 belongs_to: bookshelf

bookshelf: id, category_id
 has_many :books
```

Example that i have in mind but it does not works:

```
- @books.where(bookshelf: {category_id: 5 }).each do |book|
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you already have @books object and want to fire query on it, then you can use,

```
@books.where('bookshelf_id in (?)', Bookshelf.where(category_id: 5).pluck(:id))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a clear hiararchy, you should start by looking up the bookshelf first, then get the books collection

```
BookShelf.where(category_id: 5).books
```

Comment: this will raise error as BookShelf.where(category_id: 5) will return array of bookshelfs. So you need to use map to get all books as BookShelf.where(category_id: 5).map{|b| b.books} which will return array of books

Answer (score 0):

Use `joins` to filter the record. Try this

```
@books = Book.joins(:bookshelf).where('bookshelves.category_id =?', 5)
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Almost got it! It's `bookshelves`. You didn't explain how `joins` works though, so it looks like a kind of a "magic spell" right now.

Comment: Also, without an SQL string: `.merge(@category.bookshelves)` (assuming `@category` contains the category with `id: 5`).

Comment: It's a db INNER JOIN and the best approach to retrieve the data behalf of the associated table. For more info please read [Rails Guide : Active Record Query : Joining Tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: Alright, I know that already, add that to your answer. :) It's okay to edit answers (even others'!) as long as you're improving them.

Answer (score 0):

```
@books = Book.joins(:bookshelves).where(bookshelf: { category_id: 5 })
```

Comment: I'd be expecting an error "table `boolshelf` does not exist".